# Problema com inputmask (Máscara)

Tags: jquery-masked-input

Estou tentando colocar máscara no meus inputs, acho que já chamei os arquivos necessários, porém não está funcionando.

Arquivos:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://localhost/sprodoc-bootstrap/bootstrap/js/inputmask.js">

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://localhost/sprodoc-bootstrap/bootstrap/js/jquery.inputmask.js"></script>
```

JS:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("input.fdatepicker").inputmask("99/99/9999");
    $("input.cpf").inputmask("999.999.999-99");
    $("input.telefone").inputmask("(99) 9999-9999");
});
```

INPUT:

```
<div class="form-group">
<label>CPF</label>
<input type="text" name="cpf" value="<?php echo set_value('cpf')?>" class="form-control cpf" placeholder="Cpf">
```

OBS: Estou usando o framework Bootstrap

Comment: Qual a diferênça entre os arquivos `bootstrap/js/inputmask.js` e `bootstrap/js/jquery.inputmask.js`? E onde estás a carregar o próprio jQuery? Podes fazer um jsFiddle que reproduza o problema?

Comment: Baixei nesse site https://github.com/RobinHerbots/jquery.inputmask o pacote que vem com jquery.inputmask e o inputmask. Estou usando o Jquery (jQuery v1.11.3 ) . Acho que não está faltando nada pra ser chamado.